# How to return an array of objects with different schema in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Let's say I have `ClassA` and `ClassB`, both derive from MainClass. I would like to return a list of instances of those classes. I tried to return `List<MainClass>`, but default JSON serializer doesn't include properties from `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

Comment: Well you'd create a `List<MainClass>` and add instances of both `ClassA` and `ClassB` to it. Please could you edit your question to show what you've tried, and what problems you faced? It's not really clear what the issue is at the moment.

Comment: You've edited to provide a *bit* more information, but it would be a lot more helpful if you'd provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please explain some more with your codes.

Comment: There is no point in providing a declaration of three classes and a return statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked fine for me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<MainClass>{new A{PropA = "a", MainProp = "mainA"}, new B{PropB = "b", MainProp = "mainB"}};
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);

        Console.WriteLine(output);

    }


    public class MainClass {
        public string MainProp { get; set; }    
    }

    public class A : MainClass {

        public string PropA { get; set; }
    }

    public class B : MainClass {

        public string PropB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[{"PropA":"a","MainProp":"mainA"},{"PropB":"b","MainProp":"mainB"}]
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution, serializing it faster and returning a string. I'll test it later in the context of .NET Core and mark your answer as solution.